# google sign in error code 10: shows in toast message

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-signin

Upon publishing my application, I tried the google sign in button and an error code popped up in a toast message "10:" I'm not sure exactly what that is. I have the SHA 1 added in to the firebase database as well.

```
 // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    signup1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
                            }

        });


 //google login
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);


        }

    });
```

Comment: can you mention what toast message you are getting?

Comment: The SHA you published of your machine is different from the one Google signs in after your APK.

Comment: the toast message appears after selecting a gmail account in the white pop up box, the message displays "10:" and then fades away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple assuming this could be your problem,

Your `SHA` key does not match with the signed APK published in your Play Store.

Go to `Play Console->Release Management->App Signing`

Under **App signing certificate** you will find your key. Add that to your Firebase.

> **NOTE:** This is an instant process and your signin will start working immediately.

Comment: I have not placed my app in the google play store yet. I just had the apk file first to test how it would be before adding to play store

Comment: now I figured how to get to the app signing, and when I ran the application by installing from my android studio, it worked, however, when I generated and apk, ( not app bundle) to distribute and install from my google drive, the error occurred again. Is it because I am not generating from app bundle?

Comment: got it to work now using your help, thanks again @sanjeev